# React router : rendered page scrolls automatically to the bottom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I noticed that when ever I access a route, the page scrolls automatically to the bottom when I use `<Link>`, I am a bit confused because it is working and I get the page but it scrolls automatically all the way to the bottom by this behavior.

Here is the router:

```
import {Link,Routes,Route,Navigate} from 'react-router'

const App = () => {
  const user=true
  return <div>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>} />
      <Route exact path="/products/:category" element={ <ShoppingCat/>}/>
      <Route exact path="/product/:id" element={ <ProductView/>}/>
      <Route exact path="/cart" element={ <Cart/>}/>
       <Route exact path="/login" element={user?<Navigate to='/'/>: <Login/>}/>
       <Route exact path="/register" element={ user? <Navigate to='/'/> :<Register/>}/>
    </Routes>
```

this is a button to access the `<ProductView/>` route:

```
<Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
  <button className='btn-4'>View </button>
</Link>
```

Comment: I don't see anything out of sorts here. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the answer above is good for older versions, withRouter and history no longer exist in V6 so here is how  the scroll to the top  wrapper looks in later version :

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

and in index.js :

```js
import ScrollToTop from "./ScrollToTop";


ReactDOM.render(
 
    <Router>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <App />
    </Router>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing anymore code my guess would be that your button location is actually at the bottom of the page so when you change route you are staying at the bottom as you have no scroll to top component.

To scroll to the top on every route change do the following.

New component ScrollToTop.js

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function ScrollToTop({ history }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = history.listen(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
    return () => {
      unlisten();
    }
  }, []);

  return (null);
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

Then change your app.js to this

```
import {Link,Routes,Route,Navigate} from 'react-router'

const App = () => {
  const user=true
  return <div>
    <ScrollToTop />
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>} />
      <Route exact path="/products/:category" element={ <ShoppingCat/>}/>
      <Route exact path="/product/:id" element={ <ProductView/>}/>
      <Route exact path="/cart" element={ <Cart/>}/>
       <Route exact path="/login" element={user?<Navigate to='/'/>: <Login/>}/>
       <Route exact path="/register" element={ user? <Navigate to='/'/> :<Register/>}/>
    </Routes>
</div>
```

Comment: you are absolutely right, I have just fixed it, thank you for taking time to help!

Comment: This works best for me, thank you. <ScrollToTop> needs to be placed within the <Router> component, which is in my app.js. Thanks again.